# jquery - detect a link click inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

The iframe and the parent are on the same domain.

This is how I would do it normally:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(href);
});
```

How would I detect in the iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: This isn't cross domain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655862/attach-click-handler-even-on-element-inside-iframe-with-jquery?rq=1